# C# Connection string issue. EF code first and db context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

my config file with connection string look like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BlogDB"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\tmks.dldp\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\CodeFirstTest\CodeFirstTest\DB\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

the above connection string is fine ?

the below way connection string has been passed to db context.

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlogDB"].ConnectionString)
{
}

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
}
```

i am getting this error when i am running the code. error as follows

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in
>   System.Configuration.dll
>
> Additional information: Configuration system failed to initialize

just tell me what is wrong there in code or connection string in app.config file ?

thanks

Comment: I think the connection string setting is missing the provider type like providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" ... that might be the issue

Comment: so give me rectified code.

Comment: Try adding the `Initial Catalog=...`, for example: `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\tmks.dldp\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\CodeFirstTest\CodeFirstTest\DB\Test.mdf;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True`

Comment: First of all, why do you have to put connection string in app.config. Isn't this class library referenced in any web project , which has web.config file. If you are using any web project then it's good practice to keep connection strings in web.config and refer them in your class library.

Comment: i put the connection string in app.config file and i am working with console apps.

Comment: cool.. btw which version of sql server express localDB installed on ur PC?

Comment: the problem is in connection string. `    <add name="BlogDB" connectionString="Data Source="(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\tridip.bbakolkata\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\CodeFirstTest\CodeFirstTest\DB\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
`

Comment: Provider is missing. Look at msdn docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just give base("BlogDB")

```
 public class BloggingContext : DbContext
 {
public BloggingContext()
    :      base("BlogDB")
  {
  }

public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
 }
```

Comment: now getting this error after change made as per your code. `An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.`

Comment: may be the connection string is not right in app.config file. just do not understand what to change there.

Answer (score 0):

You did not put the connection name correctly.
You can change your code as shown below

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext()
        : base("name=BlogDB")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Or direct the connection string

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext()
        : base(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\tmks.dldp\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\CodeFirstTest\CodeFirstTest\DB\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```